# To check an input string is present in custom table of strings

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Assume length of element in table is 1 or 2.
Table: { h, fe, na, o}
input string: nafeo
Output: true

Table: {ab,bc}
input string: abc
Output: false

Please advise my below code will cover all the cases and is this the best solution? Or am I missing anything, any alternate solutions?

```
import java.util.*;

public class CustomTable {
Set<String> table = new HashSet<String>();

public CustomTable(){
    // add your elements here for more test cases
    table.add("oh");
    table.add("he");
}

public int checkTable( String prev, String curr, String next) {
    System.out.print(prev+":"+curr+":"+next);
    System.out.println();
    if (prev!=null) if (table.contains(prev)) return -1;
    if (table.contains(curr)) return 0;
    if (table.contains(next)) return 1;
    return 2;
}
// ohhe.
public static void main(String args[]) {
    CustomTable obj = new CustomTable();
    String inputStr = "ohheo"; //Tested ohe,ohhe,ohohe
    int result = 0;
    String curr, prev, next;
    for (int i = 0; i < inputStr.length(); i++) {
        // if prev element is found
        if (result==-1){
            prev = null;
        }
        else {
            if (i > 0) {
                prev = inputStr.substring(i - 1, i + 1);
            } else {
                prev = inputStr.substring(i, i + 1);
            }
        }
        curr = inputStr.substring(i,i+1);
        if (i < inputStr.length()-1) {
            next = inputStr.substring(i, i+2);
        } else {
            next = inputStr.substring(i, i+1);
        }
        result = obj.checkTable(prev, curr, next);

        if (result==2) {
            System.out.print("false");
            return;
        }
    }
    System.out.print("true");

}
```

}

Comment: Below code? Do you want us to write the code?

Comment: not able to paste the code, exceeding the size.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem have similarities to well known [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) and you can use its solutions by some customization.

Comment: not sure, this is continuous and length of the elements in the custom table is either one or two.